# Get path to My Pictures from C++

Tags: c++, windows

What is the most reliable way to get the path of My Pictures as an LPSTR in Win 32 (not .NET)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using the [`SHGetFolderPath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762181%28VS.85%29.aspx) function with the [`CSIDL_MYPICTURES`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762494%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) CSIDL

something like so

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <shlobj.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "shell32.lib")

int main() { 
    CHAR mypicturespath[MAX_PATH];
    HRESULT result = SHGetFolderPath(NULL, CSIDL_MYPICTURES, NULL, SHGFP_TYPE_CURRENT, mypicturespath);        
    std::cout << "My Pictures : " << mypicturespath << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `SHGetKnownFolderPath` is the "new way", I think.

Comment: Yes, but the OP doesn't specify the Windows version. and `SHGetFolderPath` works in the newers Windows versions too.

Comment: The OP asked to get the string as LPSTR (i.e. char-based string). In this case, I think it is best to explicitly using the ...A() ending form of the function (i.e. SHGetFolderPathA), considering that modern versions of Visual Studio use Unicode build as default (and not ANSI/MBCS), so SHGetFolderPath would expand to SHGetFolderPathW. BTW: I wonder why the OP is asking for LPSTR: in these days Unicode (so LPWSTR) should be the default text encoding form.

Answer (score 3):

Use the `SHGetFolderPath()` API function with the `CSIDL_MYPICTURES` flag.